# Why my list items don't display inline?

Tags: html, css

i just wrote some lines of code here. I want `<span>` texts to display below these `<h1>` but if i edit css  `<h1>` or `<span>` to " display: block " then the parent element `<li>` will display as block too.

```
<ul>
 <li><h1>Big Number</h1><span>Description</span></li>
 <li><h1>Big Number</h1><span>Description</span></li>
 <li><h1>Big Number</h1><span>Description</span></li>
</ul>
```

This is the style:

```
ul li {
    display: inline;
}

h1 {
    display: inline;
}

span { 
    display: inline;
}
```

How can I make the `<li>` display inline and the `<span>` texts display below `<h1>` ?

Comment: Use: `ul li {  display: inline}  span { display: block}`

Answer (score 3):

An inline box can't cleanly contain a block box.

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```css
ul li {display: inline-block;}
h1    {display: inline-block;}
span  {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [SAMPLE](http://cssdeck.com/labs/nbuguvre)

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    display: inline;
}

span { 
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the inline-block property on the ul li selector.

`ul li { display: inline-block }`

jsfiddle.net is not working right now so I can't make an example for you. You're also gonna have to delete the h1 and span style.

An example on CodePen

http://codepen.io/Tudes/pen/dyFDL

The reason why you have to use only the **inline-block** property on the **ul li** selector is because **h1** is a block element that means it is gonna take the full width of the div and the **span** will go right underneath it.